# FSharp.Core version errors during startup of an Azure worker role

Tags: azure, f#

I have a well-established project that includes three worker roles. This project has always used F#, not in the worker roles themselves, but in the functions that they call.  I've recently added another worker role to the project but the architecture (C# worker roles calling F# code) remains the same.  Since these changes I've been getting these messages after deployment:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

This happens during Autofac dependency resolution:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException", "exceptionMessage": "An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBConfig
```

I know this is a well known issue, and the solution is generally to add some binding redirects.  I've added a redirect thus:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
```

...to every project in the solution that has an app.config, which includes all the worker roles.  I've also verified that every reference to FSharp.core uses version 4.3.1.0 and has copy local set to true.

I've also tried adding FSharp.core to the C# projects in the solution via the FSharp.Core nuget package.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would need a BR here as it sounds to me like this was always working and just adding a new worker role has somehow botched things up.

Without knowing your deployment process, I would suggest firstly just performing a manual package of the Cloud Service (you can do this directly from within Visual Studio or the command line using `cspack`). This will give you a zip file which contains all the code that will be deployed into the worker role - make sure that this contains FSharp.Core (and the correct version).

I would also suggest doing a quick diff (if you're not already done so) with what has changed since you added the new worker role in.

Lastly - watch out with the FSharp.Core Nuget package - FSharp.Core is treated differently by Visual Studio and by default won't reference the Nuget version if there's already a version of FSharp.Core referenced in the project.

Comment: Thanks - several brilliant tips there.  I'll post the results as soon as I've followed them up.

Comment: Packaged the cloud service, renamed the cspkg file to zip and unzipped. Renamed the inner cssx files to zip and unzipped.

Found that there were both FSharp.core.dll 4.3.1.0 and 4.4 in there. Realized that this had been done by the installation of the FSharp.Core Nuget package.  Reverted that change, repeated the above, found that now all the FSharp.core.dlls are 4.3.1.0.

Now redeploying that version to prove the issue is still there (I think it will be as it was happening before I Nugetted FSharp.core).

Comment: Yeah, failed again - still "Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference". I'm going to blow away the whole branch build and recreate it in case something isn't getting updated during build (MyGet).

Comment: Failed again using reconstructed branch build.  Now trying again having replaced all the binding redirects oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" with 0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0.

Comment: Failed again.  The diff approach makes logical sense but there are dozens of commits (each with many files) to go through - which is hard when you don't really know what you're looking for.  Azure support were going to get back to me so maybe that will happen.  Out of ideas otherwise.  I might try paket-ising the project but I'm reluctant to do this as it's another thing for maintainers to learn when they encounter this component.

Comment: Used asmspy to look at the workers' bin/Release directories following a manual 'package'.  All the references to FSharp.Core are to 4.3.1.0.  I guess something different is going on on our build pipeline and/or Azure, from what is going on on my dev machine.

Comment: Hmmmm. The code that runs on the cloud service *is* whatever is in that zip file.

You could try paketifying the project just as a means to an end to see if it fixes the BR issue - as long as you're using the FSharp.Core nuget package and not the local version.

Have you tried running fuslogvwr just to confirm what the BR requests being made are?